# Allow only one product in cart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Running joomla 3.4.8 and VM 3.0.12

I need to allow only one product in cart. I mean, if the client add a product to the cart and then if he/she wants to add another product don't allow it showing error message like " you can't have more than one product in cart"

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the add() function in the cart controller page to achieve it. You can write code something like this

```
$cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart();
$prdata = $cart->cartProductsData;
$qty = 0;
foreach($prdata as $pdata)
    {
        $qty = $qty + $pdata['quantity'];
    }


if ($cart) {
        $virtuemart_product_ids = vRequest::getInt('virtuemart_product_id');
        $error = false;
        if($qty>=1)
        {
            $msg = vmText::_('you can't have more than one product in cart');
            $type = 'warning';
        }
        else
        {
        $cart->add($virtuemart_product_ids,$error);
```

Use the same logic in updatecart() function in the same page.

If you using Fancypopup addtocart, then use the code in addJS function instead of add() function.